# On click button enable only when checbox clicked

Tags: html, checkbox, radio-button

I tried implementing this for a radio button

```
<form>
<input name="rad" type="radio" value="Yes" onclick="this.form['sub'].disabled=false"> Agreement
<br>

<br>
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit" disabled>
</form>
```

The problem is I need a hyperlink next to Agreement so that people can click and see it then click and proceed.
but when I try adding a hyperlink to the word agreement the Button also gets hyperlinked to the same url.
Also I need to redirect after button is clicked to a different page
How can I accomplish this

Comment: Your "Agreement" code is not showing.  Try using jsfiddle.net to create an example, then paste the link here.

Comment: @JasonTFeatheringham - please don't suggest people post code elsewhere and link to it here. SO is meant for well-formed questions where a small bit of code is easily posted along with the question. In this particular case, the OP simply hadn't used the editor properly. I've edited the question to display his code.

Comment: Thanks, @BrianRoach, for the help.  I didn't see the "edit" button until now.  The text contrast is quite low.

Answer (score 0):

You would use jQuery like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Xkd5f/1/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the answer is but the question itself is unclear. From my understanding, is it works like this:

1. User agree to the agreement, so he/she click on 'Agreement' button
2. beside the 'Agreement' button there is a link to the details (maybe term and condition) so user can click it and view the page
3. After user click the 'Agreement' button, user will be redirected to a new page

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/TzLDS/

It's not very complete but you may get the idea from here. maybe someone can improve my jQuery implementation